# Difference between 'as long as' and 'so long as'

Tags: word-choice, future-time

I am studying English with *[Understanding and Using English Grammar](http://share.netassist.ua/files/a389cd670079a5bf6e95fde6c72680e1.pdf)* by Longman.

In an exercise, I have to use given the time words appropriate to the meaning to combine each pair of sentences.

> Directions: Combine each pair of sentences. Use the given time words if they are possible and appropriate to the meaning. Cross out inappropriate ones.
> In the new sentences, omit unnecessary words, make any necessary changes (paying special attention to verb forms), and punctuate carefully

Below is the question [Q 17 on page 74]. Either a, b, or c needs to join the sentences.

> I will not forget Mr. Tanaka. I will live for a long time.
>
> (a) as  (b) as long as  (c) so long as

The answer is: b. **as long as**

> I will not forget Mr. Tanaka *as long as* I live.

I don't understand why the 'c. so long as' cannot be the answer, too?
I thought the two words have same meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure that either is appropriate, actually, because neither *as long as* nor *so long as* can be followed by *I will live.* But given the question is a set exercise, it's better suited to ELL.

Comment: yes, I have to omit the 'will' combining two sentences. The answer is "I will not forget Mr. Tanaka as long as I live." But I'm curious.. Why 'c. so long as' is cannot be the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Q: I will not forget Mr. Tanaka. I will live for a long time.
>
> a. as
>
> b. as long as
>
> c. so long as

> A: I will not forget Mr. Tanaka **as long as** I live.

A lot of the difference between *as/so long as*, depends on the context:

**As long as** is an adverbial time phrase modifying the clause “I live” = for the length of time that [I live]

**As long as I live** is an adverbial time phrase modifying the main clause “I will not forget Mr. Tanaka”.

**As long as I live** = **for the length of time that I am alive**

Compare:

***As** long as* you hold on to the rope, you are safe.  = *For the length of time that* you hold on to the rope, you will be safe.

**So long as** is different, in this context, it introduces a **conditional** adverbial time phrase:

*I will not forget Mr. Tanaka **so** long as I live.* = I will not forget Mr. Tanaka, **if I am allowed to live / if I am alive**

***So** long as* you hold on to the rope, you are safe.  = If you hold on to the rope, **for that length of time** you will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Table 5 on page 72 of the Longman document clearly states that "as long as" and "so long as" can be used to start adverb clauses with the same meaning- "during all that time, from beginning to end". Both of the examples use the set phrase ""so/as long as I live"".

The [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-long-as) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20long%20as) dictionaries focus mainly on the specific meaning "provided that". The Longman definition is closer to the intended meaning in the OP's sentence, but I think that the dictionaries have correctly identified the more widely used meaning outside of the set phrase.

Looking at the set phrase, this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20long%20as%20I%20live%2Cso%20long%20as%20I%20live&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20long%20as%20I%20live%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20long%20as%20I%20live%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cas%20long%20as%20I%20live%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20long%20as%20I%20live%3B%2Cc0) shows that "as long as I live" is used about ten times as often as "so long as I live".

One very widely used variant of the set phrase occurs in the wedding vows: most denominations use "**as long as** we/you both shall live", but the Quaker vow is "**so long as** we both on earth shall live".

In these two versions of the set phrase, then, it seems that both are grammatically correct, and **as long as** is the most common.

**As long as** (but not **so long as**) is sometimes used outside of the set phrase to specify a time, though it is normal to add the preposition "for", in the same way as you would for any other time specifier. Here is an example:

> And then he said she could keep the gun **for** as long as she liked. - *The Migrant Painter of Birds - L Jorge (2011)*